# Download pdf - accessibility for screen readers

Tags: pdf, button, accessibility, href, screen-readers

I'm curious how to make an accessible button for screen readers which downloads PDF.

I know that there is an option using `href` and pass there an URL to the pdf file, and even a `download` attribute inside an anchor to open a download window.

But it's not a good way for a screen reader. The screen reader reads it as a `link` but actually, this is not a `link` because it triggers downloading a pdf file rather than redirect to another page. So this can be confusing for people with vision disorders who rely on their screen readers.

Is it a good accessibility way to create such a button? Or relying on `<a href='path-to-pdf'>...</a>` is completely enough and not confusing for people with disabilities ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either a link or a button is fine. The most important thing is that the user is informed about what the element does - i.e. it downloads/opens a PDF file. So, this should be reflected in the element's label, whether that is a visible text label or an icon that uses `alt` text or `aria-label` to explicitly describe the element's purpose.

I agree with Quentinc's suggestion to also inform the user upfront about the number of pages and size of the document - that's a nice touch that I don't see very often!

PDF accessibility is a whole other topic, but again as QuentinC points out, there's not much good in allowing a user to download or view a PDF that isn't accessible, so it's a good idea to ensure the PDF has been tested against JAWS/NVDA/VoiceOver/TalkBack to ensure it is readable.

Answer (score 3):

#### General answer and basics of file download

Both a link and a button are perfectly fine, it doesn't make much difference.

IN any case, it's very important to explicitly indicate that the link or button is going to download a file rather than open a page, to avoid surprise.

The simplest and most reliable is just to write it textually, i.e. "View the report (PDF)".
You may also put a PDF icon next to the link to indicate it, but make sure to use a real image, i.e. `<img alt="PDF" />` and not CSS stuff, since the later may not be rendered to screen readers and/or don't give you the opportunity to set alt text (which is very important).

A good practice is also to indicate the file size if its size is big (more than a few megabytes), so that users having a slow or limited connection won't get stuck or burn their mobile data subscription needlessly.

It's also good to indicate the number of pages if it's more than just a few, so that people can have an idea on how big it is, and if they really can take the required time to read it.
Example: "View the report (PDF, 44 pages, 17 MB)"

Note that similarly, that's a good practice to indicate the duration of a podcast or video beforehand.

#### Additional considerations with PDF

First of all, you should make sure that your PDF is really accessible. Most aren't by default, sadly.
You should easily find resources on how to proceed to make a PDF accessible if you don't know.

Secondly, for an accessible PDF files to be effectively read accessibly, it has to be opened inside a real PDF reading program which supports tagged PDFs, like Adobe Reader.

The problem is that nowadays, most browsers have an integrated PDF viewer. These viewers usually don't support tagged PDFs, and so, even if you  make an accessible PDF, it won't be accessible to the user if it is open inside that integrated browser viewer.

So you must make sure that your link or button triggers an effective download or opening in a true PDF reading program, rather than opening in an integrated viewer of the browser.
Several possibilities that may or may not work depending on OS/browser to bypass the integrated viewer. They have to be tested to make sure they work:

- Send a header `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="something.pdf"`
- Send a Content-Type different than "application/pdf" or "text/pdf", e.g. "application/octet-stream" to fake out basic type detection
- Make the link don't ends with .pdf
- Use the download attribute of `<a>`

The most reliable are response headers. Most browsers don't rely only on file extension alone to decide what to do.

Comment: Great answer! Can you please elaborate on why would you not trust the user's local settings to decide how to handle PDF documents? Wouldn't assistive technology users generally have this configured already? It seems like forcing this setting might cause unwanted side-effects for those not using assistive technology, but I'd be interested to hear your perspective. Thanks!

Comment: That's only my own experience. If you don't specify anything special, the PDF is loaded by default inside the browser with its integrated viewer, regardless of file association. At least this is true under Windows 7 and 10 with Chrome and Firefox (probably Edge as well). With IE11, it triggers Adobe Reader if installed but it still opens in the current browser window and it doesn't always work very well.
Safari iOS is much smarter, it suggests you to share it in another app like iBooks, VoiceDream, etc. This should be like this everywhere but sadly it isn't.